# How to set active keyboard language via a command?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, language

I use OpenSuse with LXQT.

I have three languages switched by CAPS LOCK - us,ua,ru

I want to create a shortcut to switch English without pressing CAPS LOCK. So when I press a key combination, the language is switched to English. I know how to set a keyboard shortcut, but I need a command for the shortcut.

I tried `setxkbmap us`, but this removed other languages ua and ru from the avaliable to switch to.

So what is the command to set the active keyboard language?

Comment: Read up on `xkb`, you'll have to add your own layout with custom keys for directly switching to the language. [This](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.600.7058) is a good start.